# Extreme rays, recession cone of polyhedron

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, polyhedra, discrete-geometry

We have a polyhedron $P\subset R^2$ defined by:
$P:=\{ x\in R^2$

$4x_1-2x_2 \leq -8$

$−x_2≤2$

$-2x_1-x_2≤-4$

$−2x_1+x_2≤0$

Let X={(2,0)} Y{(1,2)}

*a) Find the dimension of the smallest face $F\subset P$ containing X. Is F a vertex, edge or neither*

I found the dim(F)=1, **Does that mean F is an edge?** because to be a vertex it should be dim(F)=2.

*b) Show Y is a face of P. Provide an inequality that is valid for P and that induces Y as a face of P and shows that your inequality indeed has these properties*

I found: eq(Y)={1,3,4} and dim(Y)=2

f(eq(Y)={$x\in P|$

$4x_1-2x_2 = -8$

$-2x_1-x_2=-4$

$−2x_1+x_2=0$}

**Is this correct?**

*c)Determine the recession cone rec(P) of P. Identify at least one extreme ray of P and show that it indeed is an extreme ray of rec(P)*

**This one I don't know how to do. If anyone can help with this one it would be very much appreciated**

Thanks to anyone, who can help!